# Calling Navigator.of anywhere without context?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been setting up a tabbed navigation app based on this wonderful tutorial (https://medium.com/coding-with-flutter/flutter-case-study-multiple-navigators-with-bottomnavigationbar-90eb6caa6dbf).

Now I would like to display a modal overlay login route that covers the whole screen. My login controller checks if the user is logged in and I would like to fire an event on which the modal login route appears. The problem I have is now, that I don't have a context object where I receive the signal to display the login route:

Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/');

How can I solve this or is this the wrong approach?

My User controller is a singleton object that gets initiated at app start. It checks then the user data model and if that is not set, it wants to invoke the login screen / route.

Thanks for any pointer in the right direction.
Martin

Comment: initialize your object with the top-level context provided as an argument.

Answer (score 3):

Define a navigator key that accesses from everywhere in-app (e.g in main class global space ) and pass it to root MaterialApp navigator key property in the build method

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = new GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
```

then :

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
              navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
        //...
    );
}
```

then you can access context everywhere with doing like this:

```
navigatorKey.currentContext
```

example of navigating:

```
Navigator.of(navigatorKey.currentContext).pushReplacement(
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SecondScreen()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a globalKey to access the context of the widget u like (you have to pass it a key in the constructor) , and leave it in the global space, or static in any class.... 
although not the most elegant approach, should work

Answer (score 1):

you can use this package to skip the required context.
https://pub.dev/packages/one_context

```
// go to second page using named route
OneContext().pushNamed('/second');
// go to second page using MaterialPageRoute
OneContext().push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SecondPage()));
```